# Can't set the table width in WPF through

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I am making WPF application.I have a data grid and all columns have set their width to "Auto".When i start scrolling through the table some of the columns start expanding.My question is: Can I set the column width to fit the longest data in column at the beginning (without expanding columns when i scroll)?

Comment: post your code otherwise its guess work

Answer (score 0):

the column width for wpf expanding when the shown data need more space when it set to `Auto` then this work will be done automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is due to the virtualization of the `DataGrid`. Only the items, which are visible are rendered and the controls are reused in case of scrolling (if you are activating it). And so the width will not be correct, since the longest element is not rendered yet. A list control performs very well, although you might bind many items to it.

I think you have 2 options

1. Turning off the virtualization, which might be a proper solution, if you don't have many items to show. I've to admit, I didn't try it, so no warranty. You can turn it off via `<DataGrid VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False"/>`. For more information on the `VirtualizationStackPanel` pls have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.virtualizingstackpanel%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).
2. Another solution may be `TextTrimming`. `TextBlocks` can show `Ellipses` if the text is too long. Therefor you will have to assign a custom datatemplate to the column put the following as content e.g. `<TextBlock Text="{Binding}" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"/>`. Please note, that you will also have to provide a customer `CellEditingTemplate`, if the user shall be able to edit the values. For more information about `TextTrimming` please have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.texttrimming%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). To get an idea how the whole `DataTemplate` thing regarding `DataGrids` will work, you can have a look [here](http://wpftutorial.net/DataGrid.html).

Comment: Thanks!This <DataGrid VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False"/> work just fine.

Comment: You're welcome. Please note, that a post which answers your question should be marked as such.